# Prevent NonUniqueBeanException in Micronaut, even with using @Named annotation

Tags: java, inversion-of-control, micronaut

Why does this code yield a io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NonUniqueBeanException?

```java
public abstract class ObjectifyRepository<T> {
}

@Singleton
@Named("repositoryA")
public class RepositoryA extends ObjectifyRepository<EntityA> {
    public RepositoryA() {
        super(EntityA.class);
    }
}

@Singleton
@Named("repositoryB")
public class RepositoryB extends ObjectifyRepository<EntityB> {

    public RepositoryB() {
        super(EntityB.class);
    }
}

@Singleton
public class MyService {
    private final RespositoryA repository;

    public MyService(@Named("repositoryA") RespositoryA repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
}
```

The error message is:

```
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NonUniqueBeanException: Multiple possible bean candidates found: [com.example.repository.$RepositoryA$Definition$Intercepted, com.example.repository.$RepositoryB$Definition$Intercepted]
```

Could this be related to the fact that i extend a base class instead of using interfaces?

Every solution that i found suggested to use the `@Named` annotations, so i have added them, but it still doesn't resolve my problem.

*When i asked ChatGPT it started lying and suggested some imaginary @Type annotation :D*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error i came up with this working solution:

```java
public abstract class ObjectifyRepository<T> {
}

@Singleton
@Bean(typed = RepositoryA.class)
public class RepositoryA extends ObjectifyRepository<EntityA> {
    public RepositoryA() {
        super(EntityA.class);
    }
}

@Singleton
@Bean(typed = RepositoryB.class)
public class RepositoryB extends ObjectifyRepository<EntityB> {

    public RepositoryB() {
        super(EntityB.class);
    }
}

@Singleton
public class MyService {
    private final RespositoryA repository;

    public MyService(RespositoryA repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }
}
```